# Error when Running cor.test on few columns with apply in R

Tags: r

I want to calculate the correlation between 'y' column and each column in 'col_df' dataframe.

For each calculation I want to save only the columns name with significant p_value (p_value<0.05).

y is a vector 64X1 of 0 and 1.

Example of the col_df- 60X12000

```
 a     b     c     d     e 
7.6   4.9   8.9   6.0   4.2
25.0  6.5   4.6   13.2  3.0 

col_df <- as.matrix(df)

test <- col_df[, apply(col_df, MARGIN = 2, FUN = function(x)
(cor.test(y, col_df[,x], method = "pearson")$p.value <0.05))]
```

This is the error:

```
 Error in col_df[, x] : subscript out of bounds
```

Is this the way to do that?

Comment: 'y' = age column, I corrected i=x and the comment regarding the as.matrix. Now the error is: Error in col_df[, x] : subscript out of bounds

Comment: That's not working. This is the error:  'x' and 'y' must have the same length. Also, 'cor.test(col_df[, y], x'- the x and y should be replaced. 'x' is in the 'col_df'.I checked and both 'x' and 'y' have the same length.

Comment: I added to the question example of  the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a working solution:

```r
df <- structure(list(a = c(7.6, 7.6, 25, 25, 25, 25, 7.6, 7.6, 7.6, 25), 
                     b = c(4.9, 4.9, 6.5, 6.5, 4.9, 6.5, 4.9, 4.9, 6.5, 6.5), 
                     c = c(8.9, 4.6, 8.9, 8.9, 8.9, 4.6, 4.6, 8.9, 8.9, 4.6), 
                     d = c(13.2, 13.2, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 13.2, 13.2, 13.2), 
                     e = c(3, 4.2, 3, 4.2, 3, 3, 3, 4.2, 4.2, 4.2)), 
                class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))
y <- c(1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L)
test <- df[, apply(df, MARGIN = 2, FUN = function(x) 
  (cor.test(y, x, method = "pearson")$p.value < 0.05))] 
test
#>       a   b
#> 1   7.6 4.9
#> 2   7.6 4.9
#> 3  25.0 6.5
#> 4  25.0 6.5
#> 5  25.0 4.9
#> 6  25.0 6.5
#> 7   7.6 4.9
#> 8   7.6 4.9
#> 9   7.6 6.5
#> 10 25.0 6.5
```

The difference to your solution ist that `apply()` gives you the column as `x` and
not an index. Hence, all you have to do is replace `col_df[,x]` of your solution with
just `x`.

You can simplify it a little with `sapply()`. I also recommend not to put everything into
a single line. It is hard to read and harder to debug.

```r
Columns <- sapply(df, FUN = function(x) (cor.test(y, x, method = "pearson")$p.value < 0.05))
test <- df[, Columns] 
test
#>       a   b
#> 1   7.6 4.9
#> 2   7.6 4.9
#> 3  25.0 6.5
#> 4  25.0 6.5
#> 5  25.0 4.9
#> 6  25.0 6.5
#> 7   7.6 4.9
#> 8   7.6 4.9
#> 9   7.6 6.5
#> 10 25.0 6.5
```

<sup>Created on 2020-07-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>